# 2006 Honda Accord "Stutters" above 2500 RPM, won't rev past 3000

Tags: honda, accord

I have a 2006 Honda Accord that won't rev past 3000 RPM. Somewhere between 2500 and 3000 the tachometer starts jumping back and forth rapidly between 2.5k and 3k and the car shakes pretty hard. If I let off the throttle so that it falls back below 2500 it goes back to running as normal.

This started on a ~200 mile round trip in the past few weeks. I added what oil I had and got it home. The coolant was really low so I refilled it. I took it to a mechanic who put a quart of oil in it. In the parking lot at the shop it would rev up, but on the drive home it started acting up again. It had codes for VTEC, evap, and a bad knock sensor. I replaced the knock sensor and gas cap and just like at the mechanic it ran fine for a few minutes then went back to the same problem behavior as before.

I would suspect the VTEC solenoid but it was just replaced in March. I've looked at a couple other descriptions of VTEC sensor failure but I haven't heard any of them describe these symptoms.

Should I go ahead and replace the VTEC solenoid and/or sensor? Or should I be looking elsewhere? Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before and know what I should investigate?

I should mention, there's also a crack in the air cleaner hose. It's pretty small but I haven't replaced it yet, I plan to soon.

The specific codes are:
P0325
P2647
P0456

Update: It's running again, the shop replaced the VTEC solenoid on warranty and I think that did it. The new air tube is also installed so it's possible it was that but I suspect it was the solenoid.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! EVAP code is for a small leak, but that doesn't mean it's the gas cap. You say there's a small tear in the air cleaner hose. Is this before or after the MAF sensor? Do you know what your oil pressure is? You need to look at related issues with the codes which are beyond the obvious. The P2647 could be a lot different than the VTEC actuator. VTEC isn't actuated until ~4k RPM, so would doubt the switchover is the cause. What have you done to diagnose the knock sensor?

Comment: Is the crack in the air cleaner hose before or after the MAF?

Comment: Here's one site that explains VTEC issues: https://www.fixmyoldride.com/Honda-VTEC-system-problems.html

Comment: @FDryer thank you so much, that link was very informative!